# angular 2x nested for loop performance

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So we currently have a grid component. This grid component takes in a json which contains the configs for the grid.

What we are focused are the columns so the config looks like

```
const configs = {
  columns: [{
    key: "name",
    title: "Name"
  },
  {
    key: "addressValue",
    type: "Address"
  },
  ....
  ]
}
```

The datasource json for this config will look like

```
[{
  name: "Jack",
  address: "Somewhere"
},
{
  name: "John",
  address: "Somewhere"
}]
```

In order to render this we have a template that looks (simplified) like

```
<div *ngFor="let row of dataSource; let i = index;">
  <div *ngFor="let column of config.columns">
    {{ row[column.key] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

We noticed a big slowness when we had lots of records (350+, etc records). We then proceeded to remove the column for loop which improved performance from about 600ms to 100ms.

So the question is how can we keep our columns dynamic and also improve performance? We also briefly checked some angular 2 grid components which showed that they render columns dynamically and took in a json config with columns as a parameter.

Comment: You missed a ':' in your JSON datasource.

Comment: Please add screenshot from Performance tab in Chrome Developer Tools, or anything. also please share your dataSource, there are various reasons and various approaches, I guess that in your case it's  "too many ajax requests", please update with details about where from your "config" and "dataSource", and  what else you can do with them

Comment: How many rows you get over 600? If so it's browser related. After 600 rows the browser will load every next set different and your application can hit up the seconds. If this happen try use infinity scroll or a pagitron.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using paging for 350+ records?

Comment: The max number of rows is 1000, its an existing system so there is no paging. We may probably try and get paging in later but immediate term is current performance. Its pretty slow with 300 records as well (this is a mobile app btw). @2oppin, Don't think I can share the actual data source but the test datasource shared here but really its logically the same, columns are passed in and looped as shown.

Comment: @MilindaD, I don't mean to share data, I mean share the way of how you receive data. Suppose dataSource is getter in your Component, or ~static property, how often it mutates etc. You may have 2 reasons of  "slowness": slow data fetching, complex UI (too many elements for browser to draw, especially if there is animations). Also it's hard for mee to imagine how 350+ rows can be placed on one page...